# NSLog import and library

Tags: iphone, nslog

I can't believe how much trouble I am having finding this:

I want to use `NSLog()`

what do I have to `#import` and what library do I link to?

thanks in advance,

Jay

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to http://developer.apple.com and in the search box type NSLog(). This takes you to the Foundation functions which documents this.

So the `#import` you are looking for is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

or, if you are on Xcode 5 and have module support turned on:

```
@import Foundation;
```

Answer (score 4):

[`NSLog`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLog) is apart of the [Foundation framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just like the rest of the `NS` classes and functions, you do not need to `#import` anything if you have the standard build setup such that the foundation classes are implicitly imported.